# How to nest loops correctly

Tags: bash

I have 2 scripts, #1 and #2. Each work OK by themselves. I want to read a 15 row file, row by row, and process it. Script #2 selects rows. Row 0 is is indicated as firstline=0, lastline=1. Row 14 would be firstline=14, lastline=15. I see good results from echo. I want to do the same with script #1. Can't get my head around nesting correctly. Code below.

```
#!/bin/bash

    # script 1

    filename=slash
    firstline=0
    lastline=1

    i=0
    exec <${filename}
    while read ; do
      i=$(( $i + 1 ))
      if [ "$i" -ge "${firstline}" ] ; then
        if [ "$i" -gt "${lastline}" ] ; then
          break
        else
          echo "${REPLY}" > slash1
          fold -w 21 -s slash1 > news1
          sleep 5
        fi
      fi
    done


    # script2

    firstline=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14)
    lastline=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15)

    for ((i=0;i<${#firstline[@]};i++))
    do
      echo ${firstline[$i]} ${lastline[$i]};
    done
```

Comment: A side note, you could replace `i=$(( $i + 1 ))` with `((i++))`.

Comment: In hindsight, this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248777): the problem is better solved with a single loop that uses an external utility to extract the line of interest by line number - no need for a _nested_ loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear, but perhaps you are simply looking for some simple function calls:

```
#!/bin/bash

script_1() {

    filename=slash
    firstline=$1
    lastline=$2

    i=0
    exec <${filename}
    while read ; do
      i=$(( $i + 1 ))
      if [ "$i" -ge "${firstline}" ] ; then
        if [ "$i" -gt "${lastline}" ] ; then
          break
        else
          echo "${REPLY}" > slash1
          fold -w 21 -s slash1 > news1
          sleep 5
        fi
      fi
    done
}


    # script2

    firstline=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14)
    lastline=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15)

    for ((i=0;i<${#firstline[@]};i++))
    do
      script_1 ${firstline[$i]} ${lastline[$i]};
    done
```

Note that reading the file this way is extremely inefficient, and there are undoubtedly better ways to handle this, but I am trying to minimize the changes from your code.

Comment: I'll try the code you show. I want to see 15 different news headlines, one at a time for 5 seconds showing in news1. After 5 seconds the screen blanks and shows the next headline. The blanking takes place and much more in a Python script. Presenting just one headline already works, updating every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Based on your later comments, the following idiomatic Bash code that uses `sed` to extract the line of interest in each iteration solves your problem much more simply:

<sup>Note:

- If the input file does not change between loop iterations, and the input file is small enough (as it is in the case at hand), it's more efficient to buffer the file contents in a variable up front, as is demonstrated in the original answer below.

- As [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) points out in a comment: If simply reading the input lines *sequentially* is sufficient (as opposed to extracting lines by *specific line numbers*, then a single, simple `while read -r line; do ... # fold and output, then sleep ...  done < "$filename"` is enough.</sup>

```
# Determine the input filename.
filename='slash'

# Count its number of lines.
lineCount=$(wc -l < "$filename")

# Loop over the line numbers of the file.
for (( lineNum = 1; lineNum <= lineCount; ++lineNum )); do
  # Use `sed` to extract the line with the line number at hand,
  # reformat it, and output to the target file. 
  fold -w 21 -s <(sed -n "$lineNum {p;q;}" "$filename") > 'news1'
  sleep 5
done
```

---

A simplified version of what I *think* you're trying to achieve:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Split fields by newlines on input,
# and separate array items by newlines on output.
IFS=$'\n'

# Read all input lines up front, into array ${lines[@]}
# In terms of your code, you'd use
#   read -d '' -ra lines < "$filename"
read -d '' -ra lines <<<$'line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4\nline 5\nline 6\nline 7\nline 8\nline 9\nline 10\nline 11\nline 12\nline 13\nline 14\nline 15'

# Define the arrays specifying the line ranges to select. 
firstline=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14)
lastline=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15)

# Loop over the ranges and select a range of lines in each iteration.
for ((i=0; i<${#firstline[@]}; i++)); do
    extractedLines="${lines[*]: ${firstline[i]}: 1 + ${lastline[i]} - ${firstline[i]}}"
    # Process the extracted lines.
    # In terms of your code, the `> slash1` and `fold ...` commands would go here.
    echo "$extractedLines" 
    echo '------'
done
```

Note:

- The name of the array variable filled with `read -ra` is `lines`; `${lines[@]}` is Bash syntax for returning *all* array elements as separate words (`${lines[*]}` also refers to all elements, but with slightly different semantics), and this syntax is used in the comments to illustrate that `lines` is indeed an *array* variable (note that if you were to use simply `$lines` to reference the variable, you'd implicitly get only the item with index `0`, which is the same as: `${lines[0]}`.
- `<<<$'line 1\n...'` uses a [here-string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString) (`<<<`) to read an ad-hoc *sample* document (expressed as an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (`$'...'`)) in the interest of making my example code *self-contained*.

  - As stated in the comment, you'd read from `$filename` instead:
    `read -d '' -ra lines <"$filename"`
- `extractedLines="${lines[*]: ${firstline[i]}: 1 + ${lastline[i]} - ${firstline[i]}}"` extracts the lines of interest; `${firstline[i]}` references the current element (index `i`) from array `${firstline[@]}`; since the last token in Bash's array-slicing syntax
  (`${lines[*]: <startIndex>: <elementCount>}`) is the *count* of elements to return, we must perform a *calculation* to determine the count, which is what `1 + ${lastline[i]} - ${firstline[i]}` does.

  - By virtue of using `"${lines[*]...}"` rather than `"${lines[@]...}"`, the extracted array elements are joined by the first character in `$IFS`, which in our case is a newline (`$'\n'`) (when extracting a *single* line, that doesn't really matter).

Comment: Read all input lines up front, into array ${lines[@]}? Not sure what '@' means. Where is $filename in the read line?

Comment: @donde: See my update; I suggest you familiarize yourself with [how arrays work in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html).

Comment: Uh, rereading the input file to extract a single line inside the loop is a huge antipattern.  Just read the lines.

Comment: @tripleee: It wasn't clear to me whether the input file can change between runs, and we know that the input file is small, so I decided not to bother with buffering the file contents in the rewrite of the answer. I've  added a note to that effect to the top of the answer. In the grand scheme of things, sadly, given how this question was asked, I fear there's little benefit to future readers in general.

Comment: I wasn't thinking buffering, just `while read -r line; do fold whatever "$line"; sleep 5; done <file`

Comment: @tripleee: I see - you were thinking of reading just the lines _sequentially_, in a single `while` loop, correct? If that satisfies the requirements, then that's clearly the best choice - I guess I got hung up on extracting lines by _specific line number_. I've added another note, but I think it's now time to abandon the sinking ship...

Comment: Well good help. Still can't get script to work. To clarify: There are always 15 lines from source. Each line less than 80 characters. The newest news is always first line, dropping off the 15th. Updates happen every 5 minutes. Right now, I see top line 1, from file news1. This is how I started, only seeing the top newest line. If no change in 5 minutes, I still see the same line from file news1. My next step is to see all the 14 others one at at time, every 5 seconds. I need to still use news1, holding just 1 headline, refreshed every 5 seconds with another. No list. I've coded the rest.

Comment: @donde: Aside from exiting the script after 15 * 5 = 75 seconds, my update replaces file `news1` with  the next line from `$filename` every 5 seconds (and if  reading the lines _sequentially_ is all you need, as stated, a simple `while` loop over `< "$filename"` will do). At this point, after this much confusion, I suggest you delete this question and create a  new one, based on an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: mklement0 tried your code. All I get is the last headline of 15 and the pair numbers repeated 15 times. I added my 2 lines so I see the proper format for news1. I put sleep 1 and cat news1 to see results. I don't need to see extracted lines, just each of 15 headlines every few seconds contained in news1, one at a time. Then, I'll send it to my tiny OLED display.

Comment: @donde: I cannot help or troubleshoot based on this feedback, which is why I suggest you ask a _new_ question that omits all _incidental information_, provides sample input, describes expected results,so that others can reproduce the problem. This will greatly increase your chances of getting effective help, and is also likely to benefit future readers, which is what make this site such a valuable resource.

Comment: I thought I was clear, but I guess not. I notice my rating has dropped to -2. So I probably won't be able to ask any more questions for a while. Thanks for your pleh. Not allowed to use this 4 letter word.

Comment: @donde: Are you really banned from asking questions already? Either way, I encourage you to try again (eventually). If you notify me here, I'm happy to look at your new question.

Comment: Oh yes. If you ask too many questions determined by management, they want to 'cool off' for 4 days, and then they let you back in. It's OK. You might be wondering why I have to use both bash and python in the overall script. It's just at the time I didn't know how to use sed, head, and fold in python. Here, bash can be easier.